# `gmnl` unable to include Alternative Specific Constants (ASC) in Mixed-mixed MNL model

Tags: r, multinomial, mlogit, gmnl

I am trying to estimate a Mixed-mixed multinomial logit model using the `gmnl` package. It works perfectly when not including Alternative Specific Constants (ASC), but it produces a weird error when incorporating them. The code below was taken (and adapted) from the [original article](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v079i02) published of the package.

### Data preparation

```
options(digits = 3)
library("gmnl")
library("mlogit")
data("Electricity", package = "mlogit")
Electr <- mlogit.data(Electricity, 
                      id.var = "id", 
                      choice = "choice", 
                      varying = 3:26, 
                      shape = "wide", 
                      sep = "")

####Alternative Specific Constants
Electr$asc2 <- as.numeric(Electr$alt == 2)
Electr$asc3 <- as.numeric(Electr$alt == 3)
Electr$asc4 <- as.numeric(Electr$alt == 4)
```

---

### Latent Class Models (with ASC)

The code below works perfectly, even including the ASC in the second part of the formula (`LC_ASC_in_formula`) or explicitly with the regressors (`LC_ASC_in_variables`).

```
LC_ASC_in_formula <-  gmnl(choice ~ pf + cl + loc + wk + tod + seas | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1, 
            data = Electr, 
            subset = 1:3000, 
            model = "lc", 
            panel = TRUE, 
            Q = 2)
summary(LC_ASC_in_formula)
LC_ASC_in_variables <-  gmnl( choice ~ pf + cl + loc + wk + tod + seas +asc2 +asc3 +asc4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1, 
                data = Electr, 
                subset = 1:3000, 
                model = "lc", 
                panel = TRUE, 
                Q = 2)
summary(LC_ASC_in_variables)
## Are they the same? 
logLik(LC_ASC_in_variables) ==  logLik(LC_ASC_in_formula)  
## [1] TRUE
```

---

### Mixed-mixed MNL model

This model is basically a Latent Class model, but inside each class, the parameters are random (follow a previously specified parametric distribution).

#### Mixed-mixed MNL model **WITHOUT** ASC

The model works just fine when the ASCs are omitted.

```
MM_no_ASC <- gmnl(choice ~ pf + cl + loc + wk + tod + seas | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1, 
                data    = Electr, 
                subset  = 1:3000, 
                model   = "mm",
                R       = 5, 
                panel   = TRUE, 
                ranp    = c(pf  = "n",cl  = "n",loc = "n",wk  = "n", tod = "n",seas= "n"), 
                Q = 2, 
                iterlim = 500)
```

However, it **fails** to estimate the model when including the ASC:

1. As part of the variables in the model.

```
MM_ASC_in_variables  <- gmnl( choice ~ pf + cl + loc + wk + tod + seas + 
                                       asc2 +asc3 +asc4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 , 
                 data = Electr, 
                subset = 1:3000, 
                model = "mm", 
                R = 5, 
                panel = TRUE, 
                ranp    = c(pf  = "n",cl  = "n",loc = "n",wk  = "n", tod = "n",seas= "n"),
                Q = 2, 
                iterlim = 500)

> Error in if (distr == "n") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

2. and when including them in the third part of the `formula`.

```
MM_ASC_in_formula <- gmnl( choice ~ pf + cl + loc + wk + tod + seas | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 , 
                     data = Electr, 
                     subset = 1:3000, 
                     model = "mm", 
                     R = 5, 
                     panel = TRUE, 
                     ranp    = c(pf  = "n",cl  = "n",loc = "n",wk  = "n", tod = "n",seas= "n"),
                     Q = 2, 
                     iterlim = 500)
> Error in if (distr == "n") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

**Howeve, both ways to include the ASC parameters fail to initialize the model estimation. Hopefully, someone could help me to solve this issue. Thank you in advance.**

---

**Bonus1**: Traceback of the error.
I reduced the number of observations included in the estimation (`subset = 1:20`) to see better the `traceback()` of the error shown below. But I couldn't spot the error myself.

```
MM_ASC_in_formula <- gmnl( choice ~ pf + cl + loc + wk + tod + seas | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 , 
                           data = Electr, 
                           subset = 1:20, 
                           model = "mm", 
                           R = 5, 
                           panel = TRUE, 
                           ranp    = c(pf  = "n",cl  = "n",loc = "n",wk  = "n", tod = "n",seas= "n"),
                           Q = 2, 
                           iterlim = 500)
# Error in if (distr == "n") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
traceback()
# Estimating MM-MNL model 
# Error in if (distr == "n") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
#   > traceback()
#   14: Makeh.rcoef(beta[, q], stds[, q], ranp, Omega[, ((i - 1) * R + 
#                                                          1):(i * R), drop = FALSE], correlation, Pi = NULL, Slist = NULL, 
#                   mvar = NULL)
#   13: fnOrig(theta, ...)
#   12: logLikFunc(theta, fnOrig = function (theta, y, X, H, Q, id = NULL, 
#                                            ranp, R, correlation, weights = NULL, haltons = NULL, seed = 12345, 
#                                            gradient = TRUE, get.bi = FALSE) 
#   {
#     K <- ncol(X[[1]])
#     J <- length(X)
#     N <- nrow(X[[1]])
#     panel <- !is.null(id)
#     if (panel) {
#       n <- length(unique(id))
#       if (length(weights) == 1) 
#         weights <- rep(weights, N)
#     }
#     beta <- matrix(theta[1L:(K * Q)], nrow = K, ncol = Q)
#     nstds <- if (!correlation) 
#       K * Q
#     else (0.5 * K * (K + 1)) * Q
#     stds <- matrix(theta[(K * Q + 1):(K * Q + nstds)], ncol = Q)
#     rownames(beta) <- colnames(X[[1]])
#     colnames(beta) <- colnames(stds) <- paste("class", 1:Q, sep = ":")
#     gamma <- theta[-c(1L:(K * Q + nstds))]
#     ew <- lapply(H, function(x) exp(crossprod(t(x), gamma)))
#     sew <- suml(ew)
#     Wnq <- lapply(ew, function(x) {
#       v <- x/sew
#       v[is.na(v)] <- 0
#       as.vector(v)
#     })
#     Wnq <- Reduce(cbind, Wnq)
#     set.seed(seed)
#     Omega <- make.draws(R * ifelse(panel, n, N), K, haltons)
#     XBr <- vector(mode = "list", length = J)
#     for (j in 1:J) XBr[[j]] <- array(NA, dim = c(N, R, Q))
#     nind <- ifelse(panel, n, N)
#     if (panel) 
#       theIds <- unique(id)
#     if (get.bi) 
#       bi <- array(NA, dim = c(nind, R, Q, K), dimnames = list(NULL, 
#                                                               NULL, NULL, colnames(X[[1]])))
#     for (i in 1:nind) {
#       if (panel) {
#         anid <- theIds[i]
#         theRows <- which(id == anid)
#       }
#       else theRows <- i
#       for (q in 1:Q) {
#         bq <- Makeh.rcoef(beta[, q], stds[, q], ranp, Omega[, 
#                                                             ((i - 1) * R + 1):(i * R), drop = FALSE], correlation, 
#                           Pi = NULL, Slist = NULL, mvar = NULL)
#         for (j in 1:J) {
#           XBr[[j]][theRows, , q] <- crossprod(t(X[[j]][theRows, 
#                                                        , drop = FALSE]), bq$br)
#         }
#         if (get.bi) 
#           bi[i, , q, ] <- t(bq$br)
#       }
#     }
#     EXB <- lapply(XBr, function(x) exp(x))
#     SEXB <- suml.array(EXB)
#     Pntirq <- lapply(EXB, function(x) x/SEXB)
#     Pnrq <- suml.array(mapply("*", Pntirq, y, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
#     if (panel) 
#       Pnrq <- apply(Pnrq, c(2, 3), tapply, id, prod)
#     Pnq <- apply(Pnrq, c(1, 3), mean)
#     WPnq <- Wnq * Pnq
#     Ln <- apply(WPnq, 1, sum)
#     if (get.bi) 
#       Qir <- list(wnq = Wnq, Ln = Ln, Pnrq = Pnrq)
#     lnL <- if (panel) 
#       sum(log(Ln) * weights[!duplicated(id)])
#     else sum(log(Ln) * weights)
#     if (gradient) {
#       lambda <- mapply(function(y, p) y - p, y, Pntirq, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
#       Wnq.mod <- aperm(repmat(Wnq/Ln, dimen = c(1, 1, R)), 
#                        c(1, 3, 2))
#       Qnq.mod <- Wnq.mod * Pnrq
#       if (panel) 
#         Qnq.mod <- Qnq.mod[id, , ]
#       eta <- lapply(lambda, function(x) x * Qnq.mod)
#       dUdb <- dUds <- vector(mode = "list", length = J)
#       for (j in 1:J) {
#         dUdb[[j]] <- array(NA, dim = c(N, K, Q))
#         dUds[[j]] <- array(NA, dim = c(N, nrow(stds), Q))
#       }
#       for (i in 1:nind) {
#         if (panel) {
#           anid <- theIds[i]
#           theRows <- which(id == anid)
#         }
#         else theRows <- i
#         for (q in 1:Q) {
#           bq <- Makeh.rcoef(beta[, q], stds[, q], ranp, 
#                             Omega[, ((i - 1) * R + 1):(i * R), drop = FALSE], 
#                             correlation, Pi = NULL, Slist = NULL, mvar = NULL)
#           for (j in 1:J) {
#             dUdb[[j]][theRows, , q] <- tcrossprod(eta[[j]][theRows, 
#                                                            , q, drop = TRUE], bq$d.mu)
#             dUds[[j]][theRows, , q] <- tcrossprod(eta[[j]][theRows, 
#                                                            , q, drop = TRUE], bq$d.sigma)
#           }
#         }
#       }
#       if (correlation) {
#         vecX <- c()
#         for (i in 1:K) {
#           vecX <- c(vecX, i:K)
#         }
#         Xac <- lapply(X, function(x) x[, vecX])
#       }
#       else {
#         Xac <- X
#       }
#       Xr <- lapply(X, function(x) x[, rep(1:K, Q)])
#       Xacr <- lapply(Xac, function(x) x[, rep(1:ncol(Xac[[1]]), 
#                                               Q)])
#       dUdb <- lapply(dUdb, function(x) matrix(x, nrow = N))
#       dUds <- lapply(dUds, function(x) matrix(x, nrow = N))
#       grad.beta <- suml(mapply("*", Xr, dUdb, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))/R
#       grad.stds <- suml(mapply("*", Xacr, dUds, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))/R
#       Qnq <- WPnq/Ln
#       if (panel) {
#         Wnq <- Wnq[id, ]
#         H <- lapply(H, function(x) x[id, ])
#         Qnq <- Qnq[id, ]
#       }
#       Wg <- vector(mode = "list", length = Q)
#       IQ <- diag(Q)
#       for (q in 1:Q) Wg[[q]] <- rowSums(Qnq * (repRows(IQ[q, 
#       ], N) - repCols(Wnq[, q], Q)))
#       grad.gamma <- suml(mapply("*", H, Wg, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
#       gari <- cbind(grad.beta, grad.stds, grad.gamma)
#       colnames(gari) <- names(theta)
#       attr(lnL, "gradient") <- gari * weights
#     }
#     if (get.bi) {
#       Pnjq <- lapply(Pntirq, function(x) apply(x, c(1, 3), 
#                                                mean))
#       if (panel) 
#         Wnq <- Wnq[id, ]
#       Pw <- lapply(Pnjq, function(x) x * Wnq)
#       attr(lnL, "prob.alt") <- sapply(Pw, function(x) apply(x, 
#                                                             1, sum))
#       attr(lnL, "prob.ind") <- Ln
#       attr(lnL, "bi") <- bi
#       attr(lnL, "Qir") <- Qir
#       attr(lnL, "Wnq") <- Wnq
#     }
#     lnL
#   },#   weights = 1, R = 5, seed = 12345, ranp = c(pf = "n", cl = "n", 
#                                              loc = "n", wk = "n", tod = "n", seas = "n"), id = structure(c(1L, 
#                                                                                                            1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), H = list(
#                                                                                                              `1` = structure(0, .Dim = c(1L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
#                                                                                                                "1", "(class)2")), `2` = structure(1, .Dim = c(1L, 
#                                                                                                                                                               1L), .Dimnames = list("2", "(class)2"))), correlation = FALSE, 
#   haltons = NA, Q = 2)
#   11: eval(f, sys.frame(sys.parent()))
#   10: eval(f, sys.frame(sys.parent()))
#   9: callWithoutArgs(theta, fName = fName, args = names(formals(sumt)), 
#                      ...)
#   8: (function (theta, fName, ...) 
#   
#   7: do.call(callWithoutSumt, argList)
#   6: maxOptim(fn = fn, grad = grad, hess = hess, start = start, method = "BFGS", 
#               fixed = fixed, constraints = constraints, finalHessian = finalHessian, 
#               parscale = parscale, control = mControl, ...)
#   5: maxRoutine(fn = logLik, grad = grad, hess = hess, start = start, 
#                 constraints = constraints, ...)
#   4: maxLik(method = "bfgs", iterlim = 500, start = c(`class.1.2:(intercept)` = -4.85114128700713, 
#                                                       `class.1.3:(intercept)` = -7.69322200825539, `class.1.4:(intercept)` = 5.01582959989182, 
#                                                       class.1.pf = -1.60963678008691, class.1.cl = 0.109892050051351, 
#                                                       class.1.loc = 18.3461318629584, class.1.wk = 5.01552145983325, 
#                                                       class.1.tod = 6.12905713997904, class.1.seas = -4.37562129235275, 
#                                                       `class.2.2:(intercept)` = -4.81114128700713, `class.2.3:(intercept)` = -7.6532220082554, 
#                                                       `class.2.4:(intercept)` = 5.05582959989182, class.2.pf = -1.56963678008691, 
#                                                       class.2.cl = 0.149892050051351, class.2.loc = 18.3861318629584, 
#                                                       class.2.wk = 5.05552145983325, class.2.tod = 6.16905713997903, 
#                                                       class.2.seas = -4.33562129235275, class.1.sd.pf = 0.08, class.1.sd.cl = 0.08, 
#                                                       class.1.sd.loc = 0.08, class.1.sd.wk = 0.08, class.1.sd.tod = 0.08, 
#                                                       class.1.sd.seas = 0.08, class.2.sd.pf = 0.12, class.2.sd.cl = 0.12, 
#                                                       class.2.sd.loc = 0.12, class.2.sd.wk = 0.12, class.2.sd.tod = 0.12, 
#                                                       class.2.sd.seas = 0.12, `(class)2` = 0), X = Xl, y = yl, gradient = gradient, 
#             weights = weights, logLik = ll.mnlogit, R = R, seed = seed, 
#             ranp = ranp, id = id, H = Hl, correlation = correlation, 
#             haltons = haltons, Q = Q)
#   3: eval(opt, sys.frame(which = nframe))
#   2: eval(opt, sys.frame(which = nframe))
#   1: gmnl(choice ~ pf + cl + loc + wk + tod + seas | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1, 
#           data = Electr, subset = 1:20, model = "mm", R = 5, panel = TRUE, 
#           ranp = c(pf = "n", cl = "n", loc = "n", wk = "n", tod = "n", 
#                    seas = "n"), Q = 2, iterlim = 500)
```

**Bonus2** :`sessionInfo()`

```
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[7] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] here_1.0.1        strucchange_1.5-2 sandwich_3.0-1   
 [4] zoo_1.8-9         partykit_1.2-15   mvtnorm_1.1-3    
 [7] libcoin_1.0-9     mlogit_1.1-1      dfidx_0.0-4      
[10] gmnl_1.1-3.2      Formula_1.2-4     maxLik_1.5-2     
[13] miscTools_0.6-26  dplyr_1.0.7       nnet_7.3-17
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: At first glance, it could be having trouble with the type specification in such a complicated model. Have you tried `as.character(asc1)`?

Comment: I also wonder if the asc is a strong predictor of class, in which case you could try increasing Q? 

I have not thought through why either of these would be the cause, just suggesting some trouble shooting :)

Comment: Thank you @BryanMichael! I tried using `as.character(asc1)` but I got the same error. Also increasing `Q` I still have the same issue. Thank you anyways :)